# REST API - Retrieve Data Extension through Campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to use the REST API to find a Data Extension External Key through the Campaign ID that is associated with the Data Extension. When running the call:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns/[campaignID]/assets

I can see all of the assets associated with the campaign, and the Data Extension is one of them. It gives me the following information:

`{
"id": "174042",
"campaignId": 1819,
"type": "SENDABLE_CUSTOM_OBJECT",
"objectID": "0c5f2073-d46b-e711-b71c-38eaa7907dcd",
"createdDate": "2016-03-06T13:32:30"
 }`

This is my target - but I can't seem to get anywhere with the ID or objectID. If I then make a call to:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns/[campaignID]/assets/174042

It seems to just bring in the same fields as above. Is this a lost cause?